# Convert string of lower case to upper case? In C

Tags: c, arrays, string

My professor gave me some exercises in C language... In one of them I have to pass a string as an argument to a function, this function will verify the existence of lower case letters in the array and convert it into upper case letter;

Actually there's a function to do such a thing, but I can't use string.h.

Does anyone have an idea to do it?

```
void converterup(char palavra[])
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(palavra[i] != 'a')
        {
            palavra[i] == 'A';
        }
    }
```

Would be something like this?

Comment: The standard library have [many nice functions to help you with characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte).

Comment: I gotta find way to verify every index and it's content and then convert what's inside that location, right?

Comment: If you *can't* use that, and are content to use [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) (which arguably is the most common encoding, as its even the base for UTF-8) then take a closer look at the linked table. Going from e.g. `'a'` to `'A'` is a simple case of arithmetic. And using ASCII it's also very easy to validate that the character is in the correct range.

Comment: Also, you should find a better way to determine the string length. Unless your teacher told you to hard-code `10`.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks dude! If something comes out I'll post the code here.

Comment: It looks like it checks if it is not 'a', then do an equality against 'A', which isn't an assignment. So the code provided, as currently written, doesn't do any changes.

Comment: Use ctype.h then. `if(isalpha(str[i])){ str[i] = toupper(str[i]); }`

Answer (score 1):

you need to include `<ctype.h>` before using function `toupper`, then use it like in example below (I edited your code, need to adjust it for your needs):

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    palavra[i] = toupper(palavra[i]);
}
```

this loop will convert 10 first characters to their upper ascii equivalents

or if you cannot use standard functions, you can use function like this:

```
char myUpperChar(char x){
    const int delta = 'a' - 'A'; //'a' has ascii code 97 while 'A' has code 65
    if(x <= 'z' && x >= 'a'){
        x -= delta;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a character is between 'a' and 'z', you could just add ('A' - 'a') to it to convert it to upper.

```
char input, output;
int diff = 'A' - 'a';

output = input;
if ('a' <= input && input <= 'z')
  output += diff;

return output;
```

Comment: Although it's not incorrect, it's good to remember that 'a' has greater ascii code than 'A' and it led me few times to hidden errors, because I put result of substraction same as in your answer ('A' - 'a' which is basically 65-97) in unsigned variable

Comment: Yes, if he opts to use unsigned int, that's an important point to remember!

Answer (score 1):

I guess your professor is expecting something more basic without external functions, like this.

```
char str[] = "hello";
int len = sizeof(str) / sizeof(char);
int i;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int ascii = str[i];
    if(ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122) {// 97 => 'a' and 122 => 'z' in ascii
        str[i] = (char) (ascii - 32); // 32 is the ascii substraction of lower 
    }                             // and upper letters 'a' - 'A'
}
```

Then output would be:

```
HELLO
```

Answer (score 0):

> function will verify the existence of lower case letters in the
> array and convert it into upper case letter;
>
> I can't use string.h.

Then you have to do conversion yourself. Take a look at the ASCII chart.
Then you can notice that small and capital letters are `0x40` apart.
`0x40` happens to be space `' '`;

Loop through your array and convert only the small letters

```
arr[i] <= 'z' && arr[i] >= 'a'
```

remember  that small and capital letters are `' '` apart.

```
arr[i] = arr[i] - ' ' ;
```

advance to next character in the array by increasing the index `i++` and stop when you encounter the end of the string `arr[i]=='\0'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void converterup(char arr[])
{
    size_t i = 0;
    
    if(arr == NULL) return;
    
    while(arr[i]) // loop till the '\0'; this is equivalent to `arr[i]!='\0'`
    {
        if(arr[i] <= 'z' && arr[i] >= 'a'){
          arr[i] = arr[i] - ' ' ;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
}
   
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello World!";
    
    converterup(str);
    
    printf("%s",str);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
HELLO WORLD!
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code guys, is it acceptable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

    void strupr(char palavra[])
    {
        int i;

        for(i = 0;palavra[i] > 60 && palavra[i] < 122; i++)
        {
            printf("%c", palavra[i] - 32);
        }
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        char palavra[10];

            printf("Insira uma palavra maiúsculas: "); gets(palavra);
            printf("Valor com conversão: ");
            strupr(palavra);


        return 0;
    }
```